# Linking Mac App Against GTM: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm trying to build a project that uses the google-toolbox-for-mac. I've added it as a project dependency, and linked against it.

The build completes, but when it runs I get the following:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject
  Referenced from: /Users/mbryant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fqmbpxocylqjuggktbphorcdabqj/Build/Products/Debug/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/Versions/A/GoogleToolboxForMac
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
 in /Users/mbryant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fqmbpxocylqjuggktbphorcdabqj/Build/Products/Debug/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/Versions/A/GoogleToolboxForMac
```

If I remove the google-toolbox-for-mac library, the app runs as expected (although without any of the functionality of GTM).

I'm sure this is something fairly simple, but I'm mostly an objective-c newb.

Comment: NSObject is apart of the Foundation framework, make sure you are linking against that

Comment: Yes, I am linking against foundation. And in fact I only see this error when I try to build with GTM. Without it, the app runs fine.

Comment: make sure you have the -ObjC flag set in the Other Linker Flags under build settings